# Getting latest rows in MySQL based on date (grouped by another column)

Tags: mysql, performance, select

This type of question is asked every now and then. The queries provided works, but it affects performance.

I have tried the `JOIN` method:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nbk_tabl
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ITEM_NO, MAX(REF_DATE) as LDATE
        FROM nbk_tabl 
        GROUP BY ITEM_NO) nbk2 
ON nbk_tabl.REF_DATE = nbk2.LDATE 
AND nbk_tabl.ITEM_NO = nbk2.ITEM_NO
```

And the tuple one (way slower):

```
SELECT * 
FROM nbk_tabl
WHERE REF_DATE IN (
                    SELECT MAX(REF_DATE) 
                    FROM nbk_tabl 
                    GROUP BY ITEM_NO
                  )
```

Is there any other performance friendly way of doing this?

*EDIT*: To be clear, I'm applying this to a table with thousands of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a faster way.

```
select *
from nbk_table
order by ref_date desc
limit <n>
```

Where  is the number of rows that you want to return.

Hold on.  I see you are trying to do this for a particular item.  You might try this:

```
select *
from nbk_table n
where ref_date = (select max(ref_date) from nbk_table n2 where n.item_no = n2.item_no)
```

It might optimize better than the "in" version.

Comment: It will return multiple rows with the same `ITEM_NO`. Which is what I'm avoiding in the first place.

Comment: @Ruel . . . I found your question ambiguous.  The title suggests one thing, but the query examples another.  I finally figured that out.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed my title.

Comment: Your 2nd query is better than the `IN` method, but still slower than the `JOIN`.

Comment: If you add an index on (item_no, ref_date) then it might perform better.

Comment: Well, thanks. It does perform better. :) But before I accept your answer, mind explaining how indexing them works? I don't quite get that.

Comment: That is a bit difficult to explain in a comment.  An index is a separate data structure that maps one or more column values to a particular row.  In the case of the correlated subquery, the SQL engine can just use the index to satisfy the query.  It does not need to read the original data itself.  However, this is just a brief synopsis of indexes.  They are an important part of making SQL perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Also in MySQL you can use user variables (Suppose nbk_tabl.Item_no<>0):

```
select *
from (
   select nbk_tabl.*,
      @i := if(@ITEM_NO = ITEM_NO, @i + 1, 1) as row_num,
      @ITEM_NO := ITEM_NO as t_itemNo
  from nbk_tabl,(select @i := 0, @ITEM_NO := 0) t
  order by Item_no, REF_DATE DESC
) as x where x.row_num = 1;
```